# How to call Java WS client in Grails

Tags: java, grails

I set up WS server using this tutorial http://java.dzone.com/articles/jax-ws-hello-world (that Java client works correctly, of course) and trying to call the client in Grails project like this:

**Client.java**

```
public class Client {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GreetingImplService service = new GreetingImplService();
        Greeting greeting = service.getGreetingImplPort();
        System.out.println("------->>  Call Started");
        System.out.println(greeting.sayHello("Ali"));
        System.out.println("------->>  Call Ended");
    }
}
```

**TestController.groovy**

```
class TestController {
    def index() {
        Client.main(null);
    }
}
```

In case of Grails, exception is thrown on this command:

```
Greeting greeting = service.getGreetingImplPort();
```

full stacktrace is here http://pastebin.ca/2316018

how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Install the [WSClient plugin for Grails](http://www.grails.org/plugin/ws-client), then write:

```
def proxy = webService.getClient(wsdlURL)
def result = proxy.getGreetingImplPort()
```

Comment: Yeah I know this method, but I want to use native Java classes to communicate with WebServices due to lack of WSClient's documentation